# Spring Batch | Spring boot is not picking properties files when running CommandLineJobRunner as main class through command line

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I am trying to integrate a Spring Batch with Spring boot stater web by creating `profile("batch")`. I was able to run batch using command line with active profile `batch` and my main application without any profile. I tried to integrate Spring Config and used `application.yml` and `application-batch.yml` to read configurations. Now I ran application with profile `batch` then application was not able to pick config file.

build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
//Thanks for using https://jar-download.com

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'
    implementation group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis', version: '3.6.3'
//    compileOnly group: 'org.springframework.batch', name: 'spring-batch-core', version: '3.0.7.RELEASE'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test'

}

bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner'
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("config")
@Data
public class AppConfig {

  private RedisConfig redis;

  @Data
  public static class RedisConfig {
    private String host;
    private int port;
  }
}
```

application-batch.yml

```
config:
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
```

JedisConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@Log4j2
public class JedisConfiguration {
    private final AppConfig appConfig;

    public JedisConfiguration(AppConfig appConfig) {
        this.appConfig = appConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {

        log.info("Redis: ===> " + appConfig.getRedis());
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(appConfig.getRedis().getHost(), appConfig.getRedis().getPort());
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(config);
    }
}
```

BatchConfiguration.java

```
@Profile("batch")
@Log4j2
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing

@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class BatchConfiguration {
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    private final HotelRepository hotelRepository;
    private final int STEP_SIZE = 5;

    public BatchConfiguration(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                              StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                              HotelRepository hotelRepository) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
        this.hotelRepository = hotelRepository;
    }


    @Bean
    public Job importHotelPersonalization() {
        log.info("Job1 ========> ");
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importHotelPersonalization")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1()).build();
    }

    private TaskletStep step1() {
        AtomicInteger executed = new AtomicInteger();
        Tasklet tasklet = (contribution, context) -> {
            JSONObject hotel = new JSONObject("{\"name\":\"My Hostel\",\"prices\":\"100\"}");
            log.info("This is from tasklet step with parameter ->"
                    + context.getStepContext().getJobParameters().get("message") + " Executed : "+executed.get());
            Hotel hotel1 = HotelMapper.toHotelDAO(hotel);
            hotelRepository.save(hotel1);
            executed.getAndIncrement();

            return executed.get() >= STEP_SIZE ? RepeatStatus.FINISHED : RepeatStatus.CONTINUABLE;
        };
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").tasklet(tasklet).build();
    }
}
```

I am running application by following command:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=batch -Dspring.config.additional-location=classpath:application-batch.yml -jar build/libs/GradleJedisExample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.wego.gradlejedisexample.BatchConfiguration importHotelPersonalization  message=hi
```

Application failed with following error:

```
18:15:49.815 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'jedisConfiguration' via constructor to bean named 'appConfig'
18:15:49.826 [main] INFO com.wego.gradlejedisexample.config.JedisConfiguration - Redis: ===> null
18:15:49.827 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hotelRepository' defined in com.wego.gradlejedisexample.repository.HotelRepository defined in @EnableRedisRepositories declared on RedisRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableRedisRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisKeyValueTemplate' while setting bean property 'keyValueOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueTemplate': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisKeyValueAdapter' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueAdapter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/wego/gradlejedisexample/config/JedisConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'redisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
18:15:49.832 [main] ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner - Job Terminated in error: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hotelRepository' defined in com.wego.gradlejedisexample.repository.HotelRepository defined in @EnableRedisRepositories declared on RedisRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableRedisRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisKeyValueTemplate' while setting bean property 'keyValueOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueTemplate': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisKeyValueAdapter' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueAdapter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/wego/gradlejedisexample/config/JedisConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'redisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

JedisConfiguration is not able to read redis configuration from the `application-batch.yml` file. here is the logs:

```
18:15:49.826 [main] INFO com.wego.gradlejedisexample.config.JedisConfiguration - Redis: ===> null
```

Can someone please guide how to proceed with this?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine `AppConfig` is not annotated with any specific profile so it should be initialised for each profile.  `AppConfig`'s bean is getting initialised with default values as it is not able to find config file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue happens because you are using a class from Spring Batch as the main class for your Jar:

```
mainClassName = 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner'
```

So you are launching your app with a Spring Batch class, while this `application-{profile}.properties` resource filtering feature is from [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config).

Since you use Spring Boot, you can use the standard boot mechanism to package your jar and let it run your job automatically. So you can omit this `mainClassName` and run your job as follows:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=batch -jar myjob.jar message=hi
```

Comment: But what if you want to have multiple batch jobs defined in your project, and use the `CommandLineJobRunner` to pass that job name as a parameter?

Comment: There is a boot property `spring.bath.job.name` to choose which job to run.